# Update the same table for multiple databases within the same server in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I want to be able to update the column of the same table in different databases at the same time within the same server, but to start before starting to fill it through a temporary table I wanted to test that it came out with a database, it should be clarified that the structure of the table it is the same in all the databases and that the script would be executed going through the temporary table row by row, so I needed to test it with at least one and then replaced the declared variables.

However, I get the following error, I have not found a solution or another way to do it, I do it to avoid doing it manually 1x1 on each database and it is done automatically:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
> The multi-part identifier "test@gmail.com" could not be bound.

This is the code I tried:

```
use master
go

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @NAMEBD NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Here_goes_the_name_of_the_DB';
DECLARE @MAIL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'test@gmail.com';

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 
'USE ' + QUOTENAME(NAME) + ';
UPDATE dbo.companyconfig
SET originMail ='+@MAIL+';'
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = @NAMEBD;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

I was hoping it would update but I only get the error shown.

I also tried using `sp_MSforeachdb` and it gives me the same result.

Comment: Always `PRINT` dynamic queries first. It should show you the problem rather quickly (you're not quoting the `@mail` value). You're better off using parameters here (`WHERE name = @MAIL`, `EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@MAIL NVARCHAR(MAX)', @MAIL=@MAIL`) and avoid any quoting issues altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already managed to solve it, I did it this way:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''; 
DECLARE @NAMEBD NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Here_goes_the_name_of_the_DB'; 
DECLARE @MAIL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'test@gmail.com';

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + '

UPDATE compconfig
SET originMail ='''+@MAIL+'''
    FROM '+QUOTENAME(@NAMEBD)+'.dbo.companyconfig As compconfig;'

FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = @NAMEBD;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

It was necessary to set the field having to double the quotes.